# How can I get the Marker being dragged when event handler is already bound?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to determine which `Marker` is being dragged when the handler is a bound function? Here's a snippet of my react component:

```
constructor() {
   this.handleMarkerMove = this.handleMarkerMove.bind(this);
}

createMarker() {
   const marker = new google.maps.Marker({...}); 

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", this.handleMarkerMove);
}

handleMarkerMove(e) {
   const latitude = e.latLng.lat();
   const longitude = e.latLng.lng();
   const theMarker = ???

   // this = the class when .bind(this) registered in constructor
}
```

If I don't use `this.handleMarkerMove = this.handleMarkerMove.bind(this)` I will lose the reference to `this`, and that's how Google Maps sends the `Marker`.

Is there a way to get both `this` and `Marker` to `handleMarkerMove(e)` without creating a nested function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.bind(this)` since the `this` keyword will reference to the class itself. The best option would be to use a nested function, there's nothing wrong with that :-).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', (e) => this.handleMarkerMove(e));
```

You could also add the marker as the second parameter:

```
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({...}); 

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', this.handleMarkerMove.bind(this, marker));
```

Now you can access the marker object via the second parameter in your event handler:

```
handleMarkerMove(e, marker) {...}
```

Comment: I was hoping it would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no reliable way you can do that (aside from what you said), but there is a repo that might help integrate `google maps` with `react` [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps).